# SharePoint 2016 http throttling asp.net\requsets current is 5000

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, asp.net, sharepoint-administration

One of our clients are facing an issue over 503- server is busy error. I found that this is happened because of http throttling. When I go through some articles and trying to modify resource throttling. But stuck on limits. What is Upper, Lower limits that can use?
Please help me find out, similar below MSDN. But could not find required answer.

```
<https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc028680-ca6e-4eef-806d-527c3fd0fe20/how-is-it-possible-aspnetrequests-current-is-5000?forum=iis56troubleshooting>
```

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: not yet resolved